# Buttons to the right of Landscape not responding in iPhone iOS5 simulator

Tags: iphone, button, ios5

I have an iPhone app which runs only in landscape orientation.  There is is a button on the right side of the screen and one to the far left.

The bottom on the left side work and responds to touches.  However, the button on the right side does not respond to touches.

If I display another view and return back to the main view all buttons work.
If I move the button to just before the 3/4 mark on the screen the button works.
If I run the app using the iOS 4.3.2 simulator the buttons work as well.

I am stumped on why buttons just past the 3/4 mark on the landscape screen are not responding.

The app was originally written using xCode 4.1 and iOS 4.3.2.  I have opened the project in the new xCode and iOS SDK and this behaviour started.

Comment: Just as and FYI, it happens for any button I add to the right side of the screen, not just that single button that was originally there.

Comment: You'll really have to add some code...

Comment: I apologize if anyone spent time on this question.  I have since found a solution. Although its more of a workaround than a solution.  I didn't think code was required since it could be reproduced by just dragging a buttons on the NIB to the left and right.

Comment: Its a multi-view application.  The MainWindow has a view class added to it which manages the other views.  The problem seems to be that the MainWindow window is portrait when all other views in the app are landscape.  So buttons to the right of the 320 point are not accessible.  For the life of me I could not find out how to make the MainWindow also landscape.  I solved the problem with this code:

Comment: viewMgrClass.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
    [window addSubview:viewMgrClass.view];
 Originally the .view.frame code was not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specified the frame size for the view in the AppDelegate code before adding it to the MainWindow.

Add the code before adding the view.

```
viewMgrClass.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 320.0);
```

It goes before this line:

```
[window addSubview:viewMgrClass.view];
```

I could not figure out how to the MainWindow to be portrait.